# Dependencies are not compatible with currently expo package version when running npm start

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I recently update npm and now, when I run `npm start`, This message shows up:

```
Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - @react-native-community/netinfo - expected version range: 5.5.1 - actual version installed: ^5.8.1
```

Does anyone know how can I remove this Warning ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was pulling my hair for a similar problem with firebase...

If the expected version was higher than the installed one it would be fixed easily by running "npm install" but not this one, where the expected version is lower than the Installed one.

The fix is to run "expo update" on the project folder.
or yarn upgrade

You can also use the following:

expo install @react-native-community/netinfo@5.8.1

to fix the problem instead of using the big hammer "expo update" :)

Answer (score 3):

To fix similar issue I ran
`expo doctor --fix-dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

It just means that some of the dependencies in your project are out of date and not compatible with the version of expo you are using in your project.

It is quite common and to fix this issue i run 'npx expo update' or 'expo update' depending on how you execute expo.